# Laravel Query Builder is not working when i put 'where' and 'orWhereNull'

Tags: sql, query-builder

SQL:

```
$datas = DB::select("SELECT a.id,a.parent_id, d.action_id, d.role_id,d.department_id, d.is_created,
        d.is_edit,d.is_delete,d.is_view,d.is_audit,d.is_verify,d.is_approved
        FROM application_security_actions a
        LEFT JOIN application_default_permissions d on d.action_id = a.id where d.role_id = " . $id . " or d.role_id is null");
```

Query Builder:

```
$datas = DB::select('application_security_actions as A')
            ->leftJoin('application_default_permissions as B','A.id','=','B.action_id')
            ->where('B.role_id','=',$id)
            ->orWhereNull('B.role_id')
            ->select('A.id','A.parent_id','B.is_created','B.is_edit','B.is_delete','B.is_view','B.is_audit','B.is_verify','B.is_approved')
            ->get();
```

sql is working perfectly but when is convert in to query builder it is not working. can any on check where i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

Change on the line 1

DB::select to DB::table

Full code:

```
    $datas = DB::table('application_security_actions as A')
            ->leftJoin('application_default_permissions as B','A.id','=','B.action_id')
            ->where('B.role_id','=',$id)
            ->orWhereNull('B.role_id')
            ->select('A.id','A.parent_id','B.is_created','B.is_edit','B.is_delete','B.is_view','B.is_audit','B.is_verify','B.is_approved')
            ->get();
```